# Confused with aggregates in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

Ok: This is some of my table structure that matters here

```
CaseStudyID int
Title nvarchar(50)
OverrideTitle nvarchar(50)
```

Part of my procedure

```
Declare @Temp table(CaseStudyID int,
            Title nvarchar(50))

Insert Into @Temp 
SELECT CaseStudyID,Title 
FROM CaseStudy 
WHERE Visible = 1 AND DisplayOnHomePage = 1 
ORDER BY Title

Update @Temp Set Title = TitleOverride 
--Here is where im lost if the title occurs more than once
--I need to replace it with the override
--Schoolboy error or leaking brain I cant get it going


Select * From @Temp
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: He wants to output the title if there is not duplicate. If there is a duplicate title in the table, he wants to to show the OverrideTitle (that's my guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would replace every title that appears multiple times with the corresponding overrideTitle value.

It will keep the first occurrence of it, e.g if you have 3 titles like a,a,a only the second and third one will be replaced

```
select distinct
    cs1.CaseStudyID,
    case when cs2.CaseStudyID is null then cs1.Title else cs1.overrideTitle end as title
from  
    CaseStudy cs1
    left join CaseStudy cs2 
        on cs1.title = cs2.title
        and cs1.CaseStudyID > cs2.CaseStudyID
```

If you want to replace all of them just change > to <> as below

```
select distinct
    cs1.CaseStudyID,
    case when cs2.CaseStudyID is null then cs1.Title else cs1.overrideTitle end as title
from  
    CaseStudy cs1
    left join CaseStudy cs2 
        on cs1.title = cs2.title
        and cs1.CaseStudyID <> cs2.CaseStudyID
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether you need every single row of the orginal table. So here is my alternative solution which gives you every row:

```
SELECT CaseStudyID, Title 
FROM CaseStudy c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM CaseStudy c2 
   WHERE c2.CaseStudyID <> c1.CaseStudyID and c2.Title = c1.Title
)

UNION ALL

SELECT CaseStudyID, OverrideTitle
FROM CaseStudy c1
WHERE exists (
   SELECT * FROM CaseStudy c2
   WHERE c2.CaseStudyID <> c1.CaseStudyID and c2.Title = c1.Title
)

ORDER BY Title
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve it without using tempory table this way:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(CaseStudyID) AS CaseStudyID, 
    CASE WHEN count(*) = 1 THEN 
       MIN(Title) 
    ELSE
       MIN(OverrideTitle) 
    END AS Title
FROM CaseStudy
GROUP BY Title
ORDER BY Title
```